# Animating a fixed header to slide down on click

Tags: jquery

I have a fixed header with a contact form hidden above.  The goal is to have the form slide down when the contact link is clicked and then slide back up when the close button is clicked.

Right now my code checks to see if the body has a formUp class. If the form is up, it fires the slide down animation and changes the class to formDown.  Unfortunately, if the contact link is clicked again, it slides down even more and the close button is not working.

I would really like the user to have three ways to close the form.

1) click the close button in the form.

2) click the contact link again, and

3) click anywhere outside the form to close.

I am a student and still fairly new to js.  If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.  Here is a link to codepen with example code...
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AljKi
Thanks!

Comment: Please put your jquryCode ,so we can say where have yyou missed ,because if you have gone through <http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AljKi>
then it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines...

```
$formDown = $('body').hasClass('formDown');
$formUp = $('body').hasClass('formUp');
```

...only execute at the beginning of the script, so formDown is always false and form up is always true.

Just do [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ntqxv).

Comment: This works perfectly so thank you very much for your help. Any chance you would know how I could add the option of closing the form by clicking away from the header?  I tried adding the html tag to the click and then doing the event.stopPropogation suggested in other stack overflow threads, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: No problem. I updated the pen to handle the third case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.contactLink').on('click', function () {
        $('.contactLink').addClass('clicked'); // to stop the multiple clicks
        if ($('.contactLink').hasClass('clicked') && $('body').hasClass('formUp')) {
            $('.fixedHeader').animate({
                "top": "+=238px"
            }, 300);
            $('body').removeClass('formUp').addClass('formDown');
        }
    });

    $('.closeForm').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('body').hasClass('formDown')) {
            $('.fixedHeader').animate({
                "top": "-=238px"
            }, 300);
            $('body').removeClass('formDown').addClass('formUp');
        }
        $('.contactLink').removeClass('clicked')
    });
});
```

---

In your code it wasn't working because of these two cached variables:

```
$formDown = $('body').hasClass('formDown');
$formUp = $('body').hasClass('formUp');
```

one of them was true and other was false.